# Waterline defaultsTo not setting the value before inserting into db

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

The title is pretty straight forward. I have an attribute which looks like this:

```
    isSet: {
    type: boolean,
    defaultsTo: false
    }
```

So my goal is to have the value set to false everytime a user is created. But when I do create a user this value is null/undefined
The only workaround I found is to set the values in the beforeCreate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type should be string. This should work:

```
isSet: {
    type: 'boolean',
    defaultsTo: false
}
```